# Databricks: running variable named sub-notebooks

Tags: databricks

I have a notebook in Databricks in which I want the user to specify a sub-notebook to run.  Has anyone had this requirement and found a solution?  Thanks in advance.

This is ideally what I would like (using a widget for the user to specify the notebook to run):
[Solution if %run would allow variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGw3T.png)

- I cannot use %run because it does not allow for a variable to hold the sub-notebook's name.
- The dbutils.notebook.run is also not useful as I want to run the sub-notebook in the same namespace to retrieve the enclosed config data structures.
- Python has exec which can run a python file but that doesn't work with notebooks.
- I found the databricks-converter package which is promising but it doesn't seem to work with notebooks in the Repos directories.  I was thinking to copy the notebook to dbfs but Databricks doesn't allow this either as it reports a "Operation not supported" error on the file copy.

Comment: If its only about config data you could perhaps return that data using `dbutils.notebook.exit()`? This would allow you to use `config = dbutils.notebook.run(notebook)`. Some serialization/deserialization required.